# How to reload a page on slider navigation click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, image-gallery

I've a problem with [this slider](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/): I want to make it slider reload the page after I'm clicking the link "next/prev" in the slider or hte thumbnail.

Can someone help me ?

```
$(function() {
// ======================= imagesLoaded Plugin ===============================
// https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

// $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
// execute a callback when all images have loaded.
// needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

// callback function gets image collection as argument
//  this is the container

// original: mit license. paul irish. 2010.
// contributors: Oren Solomianik, David DeSandro, Yiannis Chatzikonstantinou

$.fn.imagesLoaded       = function( callback ) {
var $images = this.find('img'),
    len     = $images.length,
    _this   = this,
    blank   = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

function triggerCallback() {
    callback.call( _this, $images );
}

function imgLoaded() {
    if ( --len <= 0 && this.src !== blank ){
        setTimeout( triggerCallback );
        $images.off( 'load error', imgLoaded );
    }
}

if ( !len ) {
    triggerCallback();
}

$images.on( 'load error',  imgLoaded ).each( function() {
    // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
    if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){
        var src = this.src;
        // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
        // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
        this.src = blank;
        this.src = src;
    }
});

return this;
};

// gallery container
var $rgGallery          = $('#rg-gallery'),
// carousel container
$esCarousel         = $rgGallery.find('div.es-carousel-wrapper'),
// the carousel items
$items              = $esCarousel.find('ul > li'),
// total number of items
itemsCount          = $items.length;

Gallery             = (function() {
        // index of the current item
    var current         = 0, 
        // mode : carousel || fullview
        mode            = 'carousel',
        // control if one image is being loaded
        anim            = false,
        init            = function() {

            // (not necessary) preloading the images here...
            $items.add('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/><img src="images/black.png"/>').imagesLoaded( function() {
                // add options
                _addViewModes();

                // add large image wrapper
                _addImageWrapper();

                // show first image
                _showImage( $items.eq( current ) );

            });

            // initialize the carousel
            if( mode === 'carousel' )
                _initCarousel();

        },
        _initCarousel   = function() {

            // we are using the elastislide plugin:
            // http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/
            $esCarousel.show().elastislide({
                imageW  : 65,
                onClick : function( $item ) {
                    if( anim ) return false;
                    anim    = true;
                    // on click show image
                    _showImage($item);
                    // change current
                    current = $item.index();
                }
            });

            // set elastislide's current to current
            $esCarousel.elastislide( 'setCurrent', current );

        },
        _addViewModes   = function() {

            // top right buttons: hide / show carousel

            var $viewfull   = $('<a href="#" class="rg-view-full"></a>'),
                $viewthumbs = $('<a href="#" class="rg-view-thumbs rg-view-selected"></a>');

            $rgGallery.prepend( $('<div class="rg-view"/>').append( $viewfull ).append( $viewthumbs ) );

            $viewfull.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    if( mode === 'carousel' )
                        $esCarousel.elastislide( 'destroy' );
                    $esCarousel.hide();
                $viewfull.addClass('rg-view-selected');
                $viewthumbs.removeClass('rg-view-selected');
                mode    = 'fullview';
                return false;
            });

            $viewthumbs.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                _initCarousel();
                $viewthumbs.addClass('rg-view-selected');
                $viewfull.removeClass('rg-view-selected');
                mode    = 'carousel';
                return false;
            });

            if( mode === 'fullview' )
                $viewfull.trigger('click');

        },
        _addImageWrapper= function() {

            // adds the structure for the large image and the navigation buttons (if total items > 1)
            // also initializes the navigation events

            $('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).prependTo( $rgGallery );

            if( itemsCount > 1 ) {
                // addNavigation
                var $navPrev        = $rgGallery.find('a.rg-image-nav-prev'),
                    $navNext        = $rgGallery.find('a.rg-image-nav-next'),
                    $imgWrapper     = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image');

                $navPrev.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    _navigate( 'left' );
                    return false;
                }); 

                $navNext.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    _navigate( 'right' );
                    return false;
                });

                // add touchwipe events on the large image wrapper
                $imgWrapper.touchwipe({
                    wipeLeft            : function() {
                        _navigate( 'right' );
                    },
                    wipeRight           : function() {
                        _navigate( 'left' );
                    },
                    preventDefaultEvents: false
                });

                $(document).on('keyup.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    if (event.keyCode == 39)
                        _navigate( 'right' );
                    else if (event.keyCode == 37)
                        _navigate( 'left' );    
                });

            }

        },
        _navigate       = function( dir ) {

            // navigate through the large images

            if( anim ) return false;
            anim    = true;

            if( dir === 'right' ) {
                if( current + 1 >= itemsCount )
                    current = 0;
                else
                    ++current;
            }
            else if( dir === 'left' ) {
                if( current - 1 < 0 )
                    current = itemsCount - 1;
                else
                    --current;
            }

            _showImage( $items.eq( current ) );

        },
        _showImage      = function( $item ) {

            // shows the large image that is associated to the $item

            var $loader = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-loading').show();

            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $item.addClass('selected');

            var $thumb      = $item.find('img'),
                largesrc    = $thumb.data('large'),
                title       = $thumb.data('description');

            $('<img/>').load( function() {

                $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image').empty().append('<img src="' + largesrc + '"/>');

                if( title )
                    $rgGallery.find('div.rg-caption').show().children('p').empty().text( title );

                $loader.hide();

                if( mode === 'carousel' ) {
                    $esCarousel.elastislide( 'reload' );
                    $esCarousel.elastislide( 'setCurrent', current );
                }

                anim    = false;

            }).attr( 'src', largesrc );

        },
        addItems        = function( $new ) {

            $esCarousel.find('ul').append($new);
            $items      = $items.add( $($new) );
            itemsCount  = $items.length; 
            $esCarousel.elastislide( 'add', $new );

        };

    return { 
        init        : init,
        addItems    : addItems
    };

})();

Gallery.init();

/*
Example to add more items to the gallery:

var $new  = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>');
Gallery.addItems( $new );
*/
  });
```

Here is the code for the view

```
        <noscript>
        <style>
            .es-carousel ul{
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>
    <script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
        <div class="rg-image-wrapper">
            {{if itemsCount > 1}}
                <div class="rg-image-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>
                    <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
            <div class="rg-image"></div>
            <div class="rg-loading"></div>
            <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
                <div class="rg-caption" style="display:none;">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/"><span>&laquo; Previous Demo: </span>Elastislide</a>
            <span class="right_ab">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/smanography/" target="_blank">Images by Shermeee</a>
                <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/deed.en_GB">CC BY 2.0</a>
                <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/"><strong>back to the Codrops post</strong></a>
            </span>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div><!-- header -->

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Responsive Image Gallery <span>A jQuery image gallery with a thumbnail carousel</span></h1>
            <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                <div class="rg-thumbs">
                    <!-- Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                    <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                        <div class="es-nav">
                            <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                            <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="es-carousel">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                </div><!-- rg-thumbs -->
            </div><!-- rg-gallery -->

        </div><!-- content -->
    </div><!-- container -->
```

Sorry if my English is not so good, but I really need to solve this.

Comment: Could you show live example on jsfiddle or your site?

Comment: What is the actual ouput?

Comment: here is, for live example slider : http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/ i just want to modified that, when i'm clicking a button next/prev or thumbnail, the page are going reloaded & change url. like yahoo photo

Answer (score 0):

Well I have no idea why would you do that, but if you want to reload the page every time you click on the `Next` and `Prev` buttons, including the `Thumbnail` you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.es-nav span, .es-carousel img').on('click', function() {
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

This will reload the page when you click on the nav or an image in the thumbnail area.

Comment: is it work, when i clicking a thumbnail but not in the navigation.